# How to allow users to choose download directory with download tag?

Tags: html

HTML 5 has a download attribute which allows a user to download a file. But how can I allow the user to choose in which File directory they want to download file?

```
<a class="downnb"  href="http://buhehe.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/m/1.jpg" download="filename">Download</a>
```

Clicking on them triggers just download file. But can I choose where?

Comment: No, for security reasons this is not possible. The browser however does give you the possibility to choose where downloads are being stored.

Comment: The user already *has chosen* by configuring their browser [not] to ask for a download directory each time.